# Mount samba user directory at login on Windows

Tags: windows, network-shares, samba

To have user settings shared on a server for Linux clients, I would set up the client to :

- bind the user login and password against an LDAP server
- get the user login and password via pam_mount
- mount the home directory to /home/USERNAME via sshfs thanks to pam mount
- unmount the home directory at logout

This way, all users have their home directory and profile on each computer and the home directory is secured.

My question is, how to configure Windows 7 pro to do the same thing ? It would be :

- bind the user against the LDAP server
- get the user login and password
- mount the user profile via CIFS to \Users\USERNAME, using its password
- unmount the user directory at logout

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think if you set up Windows as part of a domain, it should do all that.

Comment: See [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/connect-your-computer-to-a-domain) for details.